# SQL unknown column in where clause when using max

Tags: sql

So I have a table of messages and a table of chats. Those messages have a date and the id of the chat they are in. Now I want to select the latest message of each chat. For this I need the maximum of the dates which must be the same as the date of the message. Otherwise I get a random message from this chat. 
If I do so it tells me 'Unknown column 'maxdate' in 'where clause'' and I have no idea, why. I can also order by this column.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT Chats.cid, cname, mtext, MAX(mdate) AS maxdate
FROM Chats
LEFT JOIN Messages ON Chats.cid = Messages.cid
WHERE maxdate = mdate
GROUP BY cid
ORDER BY maxdate DESC
```

Comment: Make your where clause a having.  You have two problems here.  First the alias max(mdate) isn't available in the where clause because due to order of operation. The where clause is executed before the alias is in scope.  Second, even if the alias was in scope max(mdate) hasn't been calculated yet.  Thus the existence of having.  It is intended to allow you to filter after aggregation has occured.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid. The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: @jarlh Except if this is mySQL  with the group by extensions enabled; which allows one to group by fewer fields than what are in the select; or Sybase which does something else; but still doesn't error.  but then again you said the general rule :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT c.cid, c.cname, m.mtext, mdate
FROM Chats c LEFT JOIN
     Messages m
     ON c.cid = m.cid AND
        m.mdate = (SELECT MAX(m2.mdate) FROM Messages m2 WHERE m2.cid = c.id)
ORDER BY mdate DESC;
```

Because you are using a `LEFT JOIN`, it is important that the comparison to the maximum goes in the `ON` clause.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
WHERE maxdate = mdate
```

to something like this

```
WHERE mdate = (select max(mdate) from etc)
```

Also in your select clause, change

```
MAX(mdate) AS maxdate
```

to

```
mdate
```

Comment: I think you mean `WHERE mdate = (select max(mdate) from etc)`

Comment: But then I can't specify at which chat I am looking, can I?
I would just get the latest date of all messages.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query.

```
SELECT Chats.cid, cname, mtext, mdate
FROM Chats
LEFT JOIN Messages ON Chats.cid = Messages.cid
INNER JOIN ( SELECT Chats.cid cid,  MAX(mdate) AS maxdate
            FROM Chats
            LEFT JOIN Messages ON Chats.cid = Messages.cid
            GROUP BY Chats.cid ) tmp ON tmp.maxdate = mdate AND tmp.cid = Chats.cid
ORDER BY mdate DESC
```

Comment: Works but then I don't have the chats without messages ;)

Comment: You can use Left Join instead of Inner Join